# APScheduler options

Tags: python, apscheduler

I'm trying to schedule programmatically some jobs with Advace Python Scheduler, my problem is that in the documentation it is only mentioned how to schedule with 'interval' trigger type, what about 'cron' and 'date'. Is there any complete documentation about scheduling options of APScheduler?

For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from time import sleep 
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()        

# define the function that is to be executed
def my_job(text):
    print text

job = sched.add_job(my_job, 'interval', id='my_job', seconds=10, replace_existing=True, args=['job executed!!!!'])

while True:
        sleep(1)
```

How I can schedule based on 'date' or 'cron'

I'm using latest APScheduler version 3.0.2

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
sched.add_job(my_job, trigger='cron', hour='22', minute='30')
```

Means call function 'my_job' once every day on 22:30.

APScheduler is a good stuff, but lack of docs, which is a pity, you can read the source codes to learn more.

There is some more tips for you:

1. use *

   ```
   sched.add_job(my_job, trigger='cron', second='*') # trigger every second.
   ```
2. some more attributes

   ```
   {'year': '*', 'month': 1, 'day': 1, 'week': '*', 'day_of_week': '*', 'hour': 0, 'minute': 0, 'second': 0}
   ```

And in my opinion, cron job can replace date jobs in most situations.

Comment: flycee thanks! yes eventually I started reading the source and found my way

Comment: Lack of docs? Excuse me? http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/cron.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.cron http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/date.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.date and http://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/triggers/interval.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.interval

Answer (score 1):

Based on `date`

```
job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, '2013-08-05 23:47:05', ['text']) # or can pass datetime object.
```

For example

```
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
>>>job = sched.add_date_job(my_job, datetime.datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=10), ['text'])
'text' # after 10 seconds
```

Based on `cron`

```
>>>job = sched.add_cron_job(my_job, second='*/5',args=['text'])
'text' every 5 seconds
```

Another example

```
>>>job = sched.add_cron_job(my_job,day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=17,args=['text'])
"text"  #This job is run every weekday at 5pm
```

Comment: this is no longer valid with latest versions of scheduler